# Another object calling an objects finalize method

Tags: java

When I was going through a blog, in which in an article about finalize method the following statements

were given

1. An object's finalize() method cannot be invoked by the garbage collector while the object is still reachable.
2. However, an object's finalize() method may be invoked by other objects.

I do not understand the second statement.

If it is correct, could any one please explain it ? If possible a point or two about the nuances of

finalize method would also be great.

Comment: `finalize()` is _just another method_.

Comment: Not a direct duplicate but related: [Garbage collector and finalize() method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2202557/1065197)

Comment: But, it would be automatically called by JVM before GC right ? Then what is the need for other objects to call another object's finalize ?

Comment: Read the answer in that Q/A.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza! I understand, but my only doubt is why other objects even to call some other object's finalize. Any examples would be helpful

Comment: Because as @SotiriosDelimanolis explained in his comment, `finalize()` is *just another method*. Any example of this would not be helpful because you **MUST NOT** call this method, **EVER**.

Comment: Why, precisely, must a `finalize` method NOT be called?  Does it cause total protonic reversal?

Comment: Link us to the blog post so we can see the context.